# Are negative or noninteger powers still power series?

Tags: definition, power-series

I saw definitions and theorem about power series are in the form of $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (x-x_0)^k$. And it definitely doesn't include negative or noninteger powers. Nevertheless, I saw the theorems like

> 1. If the two series converge to the same value on some interval, then the corresponding coefficients are the same.
> 2. The series can be differentiated or integrated termwisely.

be used without justification. I couldn't find relevant theorems.

My question is: are the series containing negative and noninteger power terms still called power series, and thus the theorems could apply? If not, do the theorems I mentioned as well as other common theorems like termwise multiplication (Cauchy product) hold?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format, someone please help me about the summation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: to address your first question: A series from $- \infty$ to $\infty$ is called Laurent series.

Comment: You enclose latex between dollar signs, to edit your post you click on 'edit' in the bottom left corner of your post.

Comment: @Matt: Thank you. But is Laurent series also a kind of power series? (Like Taylor series is power series.)

Comment: I don't think the term "power series" is rigorously defined. For instance, the Wikipedia article on "power series" assumes non-negative integer powers, but the article on the Laurent series calls it a "power series" all the same. Any series of powers of something can be called a "power series". Theorems are usually proved for certain kinds of power series, e.g. Taylor series and Laurent series, or for series in general; if you come across a theorem that claims to apply to "power series", you should probably look at its proof to decide whether it assumes non-negative integer powers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Power series" does not have a fixed meaning. Generally, but not always, it means a series with non-negative integer exponents, and most theorems you have seen proved about power series are about this case. Many of these theorems extend to [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) with a fixed negative lower bound away from $x_0$, and many of them can be proven just by multiplying by the appropriate power of $x - x_0$ and using the corresponding theorem for ordinary power series. If you want more assurance than this, Laurent series are usually treated in books on complex analysis.

Comment: Why non-negative integer coefficients? I'd say 'generally' (such as the ones encountered in real and complex analysis) the coefficients are real or complex numbers?

Comment: Er, exponents. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this question has been bothering me since I learned the Laurent series because the book only gives theorems in the form of non-negative powers. And the author may naturally think there is no difference. The only thing I could find is that uniformly converged series can be differentiated termwisely. Now in the study of differential equation, the fraction power appears, and I have no idea which theorems can be used. Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: @LLS: that depends. There's a big difference between exponents with denominators dividing a fixed positive integer (since you can make a simple substitution to deal with this) and exponents with denominators which get arbitrarily large in lowest terms. I don't know anything about convergence properties of the latter.

Answer (score 2):

- A ["formal power series"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) has only non-negative exponents
- A ["Laurent series"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) allows negative exponents too
- A ["Puiseux series"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) allows fractional exponents too (with restriction)